# New id by old id & status

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a data like this

| `client_id` | `code` | `date1` | `date2` | `t` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2957 | 1029 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2000-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 60 |
| 2957 | 1029 | 2000-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 2000-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 122 |
| 2957 | 1029 | 2000-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2001-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 184 |
| 2957 | 1051 | 2001-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2001-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 59 |
| 2957 | 1051 | 2001-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 2001-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 275 |
| 2957 | 1051 | 2001-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 2002-06-03 00:00:00.000 | 184 |
| 2957 | 1029 | 2002-06-03 00:00:00.000 | 2003-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 271 |
| 2957 | 1029 | 2003-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 2004-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 337 |
| 2957 | 1029 | 2004-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2004-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 182 |
| 2957 | 1029 | 2004-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 2004-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 122 |

Where `client_id` is client's id, `code` is a status, `date1` is a date of begining, `date2` is a date of ending, and `t` is difference between the dates. And the data `ORDER BY date1`

I suppose that I have to make `newid` like

```
client_id   code    date1                  date2                 t     newid 
2957    1029    2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 2000-03-01 00:00:00.000 60      1
2957    1029    2000-03-01 00:00:00.000 2000-07-01 00:00:00.000 122     1
2957    1029    2000-07-01 00:00:00.000 2001-01-01 00:00:00.000 184     1
2957    1051    2001-01-01 00:00:00.000 2001-03-01 00:00:00.000 59      2
2957    1051    2001-03-01 00:00:00.000 2001-12-01 00:00:00.000 275     2
2957    1051    2001-12-01 00:00:00.000 2002-06-03 00:00:00.000 184     2
2957    1029    2002-06-03 00:00:00.000 2003-03-01 00:00:00.000 271     3
2957    1029    2003-03-01 00:00:00.000 2004-02-01 00:00:00.000 337     3
2957    1029    2004-02-01 00:00:00.000 2004-08-01 00:00:00.000 182     3
2957    1029    2004-08-01 00:00:00.000 2004-12-01 00:00:00.000 122     3
```

so that id is determined by `id`, `code` and date order
`id` get `newid` when he change code, The client changes the code over time, the code can take on the same value after a while, but I would like the client to receive a new unique code in this case
But I do not know how to make it.

Comment: Please explain (in more detail) where those `newid` values are coming from.

Comment: How about `SELECT client_id, code, client_id + code + ROW_NUMBER() AS newid OVER ( PARTITION BY client_id, code ORDER BY date1, date2 ) FROM tbl` ?

Comment: What is your actual expected result?

Comment: @Stu to make newid

Comment: @Dai it's very close, but ROW_NUMBER is rolling number not constant

Comment: @Edward What "constant" value would you prefer it had?

Comment: @Dai in your solution we get
`2957+1029+1`
`2957+1029+2`
`2957+1029+3`
`2957+1051+1`
and I expect
`2957+1029+N`
`2957+1029+N`
`2957+1029+N`
`2957+1051+M`

Like this

Comment: @Edward Where is `N` coming from and what is its value? What about `M`?

Comment: @Dai I'd like to an answer to this

Comment: @Edward Your question is still unclear.

Comment: @Dai I want to get NEWID by id, code and odered dates

Comment: @Edward But you haven't explained what "ordererd dates" _specifically_ means. (Why not create a DBFiddle or SQLFiddle and play-around yourself?)

Comment: @Dai id get newid when he change code and changing is defined by date

Comment: So does `SELECT client_id, code, client_id + code + ROW_NUMBER() AS newid OVER ( PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date1, date2 ) FROM tbl` work then? (I changed `PARTITION BY client_id, code` to just `PARTITION BY code`).

Comment: This is a typical gaps-and-islands grouping, it's not clear though, still, what your desired results are. The table below the "I suppose" comment or the sums of values.

Comment: @Stu The client changes the code over time, the code can take on the same value after a while, but I would like the client to receive a new unique code in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following using `LAG` window function to check whenever the code is changed while the date1 is increasing:

```
SELECT client_id,code, date2, t,
       SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY date1) newid
  FROM
  (
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN CODE <> LAG(code, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY date1) 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END AS flag
   FROM table_name
  ) T
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/twfBhjXI).

This query supposes there is no code value = 0 in the table. You may replace the 0 in`LAG(code, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY date1)` with any other value that is not existed in the table, i.e. -1.

Comment: fantasic!!! it what i want to get

Comment: Happy for you, you may also [try this](https://dbfiddle.uk/NqOs52IJ) using `ROW_NUMBER` function, but I think the posted answer is more elegant.

Comment: I tried to use ROW_NUMBER() but I can't how to solve with it(

Comment: I don't know why this answer got downvote, if there is an issue with it, kindly let us know.

Comment: I gave a upvote

Comment: Yes I know, but it seems that somebody else have noticed a problem with this answer.